# For data error checking: Is there a way to avoid using a dictionary for a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data that looks like this:

```
Observation 1  
Type : 1  
Color: 2  

Observation 2  
Color: 2  

Resolution: 3
```

Originally what I had done was to attempt to create a csv that looked like:

```
1,2  
2,3  # Only problem here is that the data should look like this 1,2,\n ,2,3 #
```

I performed the following operation:

```
while linecache.getline(filename, curline):  
    for i in range(2):    
        data_manipulated = linecache.getline(filename, curline).rstrip()    
        datamanipulated2 = data_manipulated.split(":")  
        datamanipulated2.pop(0)  
        lines.append(':'.join(datamanipulated2))
```

This is quite a large dataset and I tried to find ways to verify that the above problem doesn't happen so that I can compile the data appropriately and with checks. I came across dictionaries, however, performance is a big issue for me and I would prefer lists if that's possible (at least, my understanding is that dictionaries can be significantly slower?). I was just wondering if anyone had any suggestions on the quickest and most robust way to do this?

Comment: Umm, what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
input_file = open('/path/to/input.file')
results = []
for row in file:
    m = re.match('Observation (\d+)', row)
    if m:
        observation = m.group(1)
        continue
    m = re.match('Color: (\d+)', row)
    if m:
        results.append((observation, m.group(1),))
        print "{0},{1}".format(*results[-1])
```

You can speedup using precompiled regular expressions.